# Does rescore support nested queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I am trying to rescore my query results using a nested query, but I get the following exception, which I believe means that rescore does not support nested queries:

```
nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[rescore doesn't support [path]];
```

Is that so ?

The nested objects contain a key field that should be matched and a weight field that should be used as score. Here is the query:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
 "query" : {
    "match" : {
       "field1" : {
          "query" : "my_query_string",
          "type" : "boolean"
       }
    }
 },
 "rescore" : {
    "window_size" : 50,
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "path.to.nested.object",
        "score_mode" : "avg",
        "query": {
          "function_score": {
            "query":{
              "constant_score": {
                "query": { 
                  "match": {
                    "path.to.nested.object.key": "my_query_string"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "script_score": {
              "script": "doc['path.to.nested.object.weight'].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your query With re-score you need to use rescore_query since [query_rescorer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-rescore.html#_query_rescorer) is the only implementation supported at the moment.

The following should work :

```
POST myindex/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "field1": {
            "query": "my_query_string",
            "type": "boolean"
         }
      }
   },
   "rescore": {
      "window_size": 50,
      "query": {
         "rescore_query": {
            "nested": {
               "path": "path.to.nested.object",
               "score_mode": "avg",
               "query": {
                  "function_score": {
                     "query": {
                        "constant_score": {
                           "query": {
                              "match": {
                                 "path.to.nested.object.key": "my_query_string"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "script_score": {
                        "script": "doc['path.to.nested.object.weight'].value"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: For the record: using the python API, this is reflected by the fact that the rescore attribute of the Query.search takes a pyes.query.Search object, not a pyes.query.RescoreQuery one.